# Static member function throwing error

Tags: c++, static-methods

If I try to execute below program then it is giving error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class book {
    static int i;
  public :
        static void set_data(void) // static member function
        {
            i++;
            cout<<i<<endl;
        }
};

int book :: i = 0;

int main()
{
    cout<<book :: set_data() << endl; // trying to display the static member function data here but it is giving error
}
```

If we want to use static member function then is it necessary that we need to have return static argument?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (‘**why isn't this code working?**’) must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're trying to print out the return value of `set_data()` which is `void`, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0):

`set_data` has a `void` return type so therefore cannot be used with `cout`. To remedy that, have `set_data` actually *return* something that you can output with `std::cout`:

```
static int set_data(void)
{
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

(You don't need to return a "static argument"; the `static` in this context means that you cannot access non-`static` class member data or functions.)

Then `cout << book::set_data() << endl;` will be fine. Alternatively, write

`cout << book::i << endl;`

with `i` set to `public` access.